# How to pass header value in angularjs resources

Tags: angularjs

I define custom post method in my resources. One of the post is require the header. I just want to set header value dynamically from controller. Written code is not working. It is not setting up the headers

**Service**

```
return $resource(Config.getURL() + '/api/:request/', {
        request: '@request'
    },
    {
      getmylocation:{
        method:'GET',
        params:{
          request:'getmylocation'
        },
        headers:{
          'token':token
      }

    });
```

**Controller**

```
var token ="ad234saf3dsf32442werw"
apiService.getmylocation(token)
```

Comment: use angular interceptors

Comment: This token is particular for this request. So there is need to use interceptors

Answer (score 0):

I would create a service to intercept the requests and add a header with the token like this:

```
angular.module('common').factory('xsrfTokenInterceptor', function(principal, $location) {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            //principal is the service that stores my user information and his token
            var identity = principal.identity();
            if (identity !== "undefined" && identity !== undefined && identity !== null) {
                var sessionToken = identity.session;

                if (sessionToken !== "undefined" && sessionToken !== undefined) {
                    config.headers['X-Csrf-Token'] = sessionToken;
                }
                return;
            } else{
              $location.url('/signin');
               }
            return;

        }
    };
});
```

I hope this helps